# Making a spatial link to points within polygons in the field calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, field-calculator, point, aggregate

I have a polygon shapefile of the counties in the UK and a separate point shapefile of project sites.

Within the project sites attribute table I would like to add a new virtual column with the name of the county that the point sits in determined by the polygon it is in. I have tried

```
aggregate( 'County and Unitary Authority',  'concatenate', 
"county",  within( $geometry,  geometry(@parent) ))
```

but I know this is wrong. Which aggregate do I use instead of `concatenate` and is `within` the right filter to use?

I need a method like this with NO use of plugins or making new layers.

Also, does `@parent` literally mean `@parent` or does parent mean the name of the parent layer i.e. `@County and Unitary Authority`?

Comment: You need to switch within (a,b) to within(geometry(@parent), $geometry) or use contains ($geometry, geometry(@parent)). This should help you to understand @parent. Someone just helped me with a similar question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342386/aggregates-functions-qgis-calculating-area-explained/342399#342399

Comment: Thank you, this worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aggregate('County and Unitary Authority', 'concatenate', 
"county", within(geometry(@parent), $geometry))